# Access the Next Div Inside Host Binding Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I want to access the next div on which the directive is placed.

My Directive

```
import {Directive, HostBinding, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector:'[tDropdown]'
})

export class DropdownDirective{

  @HostBinding('class.hidden') get opened(){
      return this.isOpen;
  }

  @HostListener('click') open(){
      this.isOpen = false ;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') close(){
    this.isOpen = true;
  }

  private isOpen = true;

}

<div class="well box" tDropdown>
          <span>Group :-</span>{{entry.key}}
            <div> // access this div from the directive
              <table class="table">
                  <thead class="thead-inverse">
                  <tr>
```

How to access the subsequent div from the element on which directive is placed ?

Answer (score 3):

```ts
  class DropdownDirective {

    constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterContentInit() {
      var div = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('div')
      div.classList.add('hidden');
    }
```

If you want to do it on the parent component

```ts
@ViewChild(DropdownDirective, {read: ElementRef}) elRef:ElementRef;

click() {
  var div = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('div')
  div.classList.add('hidden');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gunter Actually I want to add the class hidden to the subsequent div from where the directive is placed

Comment: Means Actually i want to Toggle the Class hidden on the subsequent div depending upon if the mouse is clicked on the directive element and apply the class hidden again if mouse leaves, I hope i was able to explain

Comment: You should be able to figure it out from there yourself ;-) `nativeElement` returns the DOM element. From there everything is the same as plain JS. You can just use `toggle` instead of `add` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: It actually Hides the div on which the directive is placed .
I placed the directive on a div like this <div tDropdown> and it hides this element instead of the child div iniside that div

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector says it queries the first descendant that matches the query. Therefore it's hard for me to imagine what's going on on your site. Did you put the code in my answer to the directive or the parent component where you use the directive?

Comment: I put it on the parent component where i am placing the directive

Comment: and now i am getting this error Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Comment: What do you mean with "and now"? What have you changed?

Comment: I changed this to  var div = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('div ~ div')
in order to get the child elements , but the hidden only applies to all except the first div  element

Comment: Rather change it like shown in my updated answer. or use `>` or ` ` (space) instead of `~`.